# jquery.autocomplete.js JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

i'm trying to make autocomplete with jquery.autocomplete.js. Unfortunately when i try to type anything to input, the debugger appeared with SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.
I'm still new with codeigniter, so can anyone help me with this?

Java Script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
      $("#asisten").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/asisten/search"
      });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function search()
{   
    $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data = $this->db->from('mahasiswa')->like('nim',$keyword)->get();  

    foreach($data->result() as $row)
    {
        $arr['query'] = $keyword;
        $arr['suggestions'][] = array(
            'nama'  =>$row->nama
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Input HTML

```
<input id="asisten" type="search">
```

JSON data

```
{"query":"7","suggestions":[{"nama":"Pedro Nadirio"},{"nama":"Antony Hartono"},{"nama":"Juan"},{"nama":"Yonathan Aditya"},{"nama":"Edwin Widhiyanto"},{"nama":"Windy Hendra S"}]}
```

Comment: Could you show us the JSON data that is being produced?

Comment: Edited for JSON data

Answer (score 0):

In your controller: try like this..

```
public function search()
    {   
        $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $data = $this->db->from('mahasiswa')->like('nim',$keyword)->get();  

        foreach($data->result_array() as $row)
        {
         $arr[] = $row['nama'];//array of namas
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

Comment: dont forget to load `url` helper first.

Comment: It's still the same, anyway when i try to click the jquery.autocomplete.js, it appoint me to this js code 
var result = typeof response === 'string' ? $.parseJSON(response) : response;